# Using a certificate in Azure Active Directory to sign and return an access token when called from Postman

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to get an access token from Azure Active Directory, where I have registered an app and uploaded a certificate (in Certificates and secrets blade). AD should use this certificate to sign the access token that it will send in the response. I would like to get the access token response in Postman.

Please suggest a general method or steps to setup postman and call AD.

Answer (score 1):

Please see this [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#second-case-access-token-request-with-a-certificate).

```
POST /{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1               // Line breaks for clarity
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default
&client_id=97e0a5b7-d745-40b6-94fe-5f77d35c6e05
&client_assertion_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Aclient-assertion-type%3Ajwt-bearer
&client_assertion=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Imd4OHRHeXN5amNScUtqRlBuZDdSRnd2d1pJMCJ9.eyJ{a lot of characters here}M8U3bSUKKJDEg
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

I think all the parameters are clear except `client_assertion`, which is the aforementioned signed JWT token.

You need to generate the JWT Token by following [certificate credentials](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Client-Assertions).

And then use this `client_assertion` in Postman.

[image]

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Allen, Thank you very much for your answer, I have been through these articles, but the main challenge is getting the "client_assertion". So, every time I have to get the "client_assertion" JWT externally and copy it to the postman request ?
Later, If I plan to call the token URL from another platform like any IBM tools, how can I generate the "client_assertion" JWT there without the MSAL library ?

Also, Is there another way to do authentication using a certificate ?

Comment: @MukkuP I'm afraid that you have to get "client_assertion" JWT externally. Postman is only for test.  You may need to use a packet capture tool to capture the request to generate the "client_assertion" JWT via MSAL. Then use webclient to call this request directly on other platforms. There should be no other way except client_assertion.

Comment: @MukkuP I'm afraid that you have to get "client_assertion" JWT externally. Postman is only for test. You may need to use a packet capture tool to capture the request to generate the "client_assertion" JWT via MSAL. Then you can see if it's possible to use webclient to call this request directly on other platforms. This is just a guess. There should be no other way except client_assertion.

Comment: @MukkuP If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.